# PHP Sentence Search - search keywords (MySQL) in a sentence

Tags: php, mysql, search, keyword, sentence

In general, keywords are searched in MySQL field, for example;

[tbl_hp] id, title

```
1, Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone
2, Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
3, Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban
4, Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire
5, Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix
6, Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince
7, Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows
```

PHP

```
$keyword = "Philosopher";
$keyword = "Harry Potter";
```

SQL

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_hp` WHERE `title` LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%';
```

Then results are;

```
"Philosopher" => 1
"Harry Potter" => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

But how to do this?

[tbl_hp_keywords] id, keyword

```
1, philosopher
2, chamber
3, azkaban
4, goblet
5, phoenix
6, prince
7, hallows
8, prisoner
9, Prisoner of Azkaban
10, Half-Blood Prince
```

PHP

```
$keyword = "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets";
$keyword = "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban";
$keyword = "Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince";
```

Then results are;

```
"Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets" => 2
"Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban" => 3,8,9 => or even better result is 9
"Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince" => 6,10 => or even better resurt is 10
```

Any help or ideas on how to do this... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275215/search-keywords-that-matches-data-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$keywords = explode(' ', $keyword);
foreach($keywords AS $key){
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl_hp_keywords WHERE keyword = '$key'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $ids[] =$result['id'];
    }
}
$answer[$keyword] = implode(',', $ids);
```

or try this one

```
$keyword = 'Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets';
$keywords = explode(' ', $keyword);
$modifiedKeyword = implode("', '", $keywords);
$sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl_hp_keywords WHERE keyword IN ('$modifiedKeyword')";
try {
    $hostname = 'servername';
    $dbname = 'dbname';
    $username = 'username';
    $pw = "password";
    $pdo = new PDO("mssql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $pw);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
}
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

for ($i = 0; $row = $query->fetch(); $i++) {
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
}

unset($pdo);
unset($query);
```

Comment: I would advise you edit your answer to not use `mysql_` functions.

Comment: @Suresh, Thank you for the code. I wonder how can this be optimized for keywords in MySQL table (e.g. [tbl_hp_keywords] 9, 'Prisoner of Azkaban')?